# How to calculate the average true range - scipy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Im working with OHLC data and I want to implement the formula below in my script
[ATR formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiSAZ.png)

Here is how I used to do it in Excel [1D ATR excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI1MA.png)

As for python, here is how far I got in my resoning

```
 df = pd.read_csv('^GSPC.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=['Date'])
 df['True Range'] = df['High'] - df['Low']
 df['1D ATR'] = df['True Range'].rolling(2).sum()/2/???
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation.

In your example it would be

```
mean = df['True Range'].mean()
print(mean)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Answer (score 0):

Using your excel formula, you're almost there, all you need to do is to divide by `df['Open']` at the end. Basic example below:

```
d = {'Date':['2020-07-02', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-30'],
'Open':[3143.64, 3105.92, 3050.2],
'High':[3165.81, 3128.44, 3111.51],
'Low':[3124.52, 3101.17, 3047.83]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['True Range'] = df['High'] - df['Low']
df['1D ATR'] = (df['True Range'].rolling(2).sum()/2)/df['Open']
df.head()
```

Gives you the 1D ATR numbers that you obtained in excel:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5yH.png)